# How to fill large 1" gap between preform laminate countertop and wall

Tags: countertops

We are trying to save money and replaced an old laminate countertop with a newer preform laminate countertop, where the backsplash is part of the laminate countertop. The countertop is an "L" shape, so we have the pre-cut miter ends that join together in the corner. The problem is that the walls seem to have a serious bow to them and where the countertop pieces join in the corner, there is about a 1 inch gap between the backsplash and the wall.  The counters are flush up against the wall at the furthest ends from the corner.  Is there any way to fill in this gap?

![countertop with 1 inch gap in corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cak7V.jpg)

Comment: is the gap a gradual increase from one end to the other? If so, it sounds like your walls aren't square. Might be easier to fix that (cut out the wallboard, shim the studs, put new wallboard back) than to change the cabinets/countertop.

Comment: Do you have a photo of that countertop as it currently fits or doesn't fit? Having the back lip built into it as you seem to be describing would make scribing it to the wall difficult, and would seem to leave you only with the choices of either squaring up the walls or installing a bit of trim between the top and the wall to cover the gap (and possibly scribe that to fit)...

Comment: yes, the gap is gradual, so the walls aren't square. I'm hoping there's a way we can do a fix that looks "good enough" without having to take out cabinets and square the wall. This would be too big of a project for us.

Comment: There are hanging cabinets above the countertop. Could we put some tile to "build out" the wall and then do some extra caulking in the corner where the gap is the widest?

Comment: Old post but a comment for anyone who reads this with the same issue. "*Could we put some tile to "build out" the wall *" I did that recently with a kitchen that had the same issue but the gap was only about a 1/2". A 1" gap is more than i would think is doable, it  would result in the tile build out standing proud of the backsplash where there is no gap. I Think the best and proper way to address this is have the countertop custom made, or modified to fit the angles of  the out of square walls.

Answer (score 1):

If the walls aren't square, I bet the cabinets aren't square as well.  And nothing says your counter top has to be square as well.  The best way to hide out of square rooms is to try and match the existing angles.  In this case you will need to make the miter cut a little bit off 45, probably 44.  A small angle change can make a huge difference when getting to get things to fit.  And even then a slight difference in the overhang on the cabinets will not be as noticeable as any means trying to fix the gap between the counter and wall.

Answer (score 1):

[This rough-cut stone backsplash](http://www.stilettosanddiapers.com/2012/03/diy-stone-backsplash-with-airstone.html) is pretty popular these days and is super easy to install (just did our kitchen with a similar product).  It can be bonded right to the sheetrock.  It should be thick enough to hide your gap.  If you need it a bit thicker, you can screw some backer-board to the wall and bond to that.  If it's your style, go for it.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! We just went to pick some up. I think this is going to be the easiest fix.  We couldn't scribe our countertop to fit correctly because it is a big enough difference that it would mess up the backsplash if we cut it down as much as it needs.  This airstone will hang over more in some places and less in others, but it won't be so noticeable in the back corner under the cabinets. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You need to plane your bench top in to fit. 
Then you will be able to push it back.

Then check if you have the same over hang from cupboards to bench top. 
If it's a little bit out don't worry about it as long as it looks ok. (can't get perfect with old kitchen)

Then if there is still a small gap you need to fill it with no more gaps / silicone. 
Need to silicone it anyway to stop water damage.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem so I found two ways to fix before we use epoxy to cover an old ugly formica countertop in a rental.

1) buy the foam filler used for cracks in windows-it is sold in large canisters that can be used without an application gun.  This material can be painted, sanded etc.  Level to countertop.

2) Use bondo over foam

If your gap is large like ours 1-2" we used a foam filler and shoved into the gap and then applied the sprayable foam or bondo, then scraped and sanded until level.  Put epoxy over this and worked amazingly well.

Answer (score -2):

A 1x2 will also suffice. Cut paint, polish, or whatever. You can also set in a little deeper and finishe off with corner molding.